# How to get user id in wordpress after registered?

Tags: wordpress, sms-gateway, one-time-password

I am working on sending OTP to user and verify it.

I am using wordpress and I created mobile number field in default registration form and when user submit registration form , then he will be receive otp which we generated through an algorithm and used sms API for sending sms.

After submit the registration form , he will redirect to one page in that page i want to get registered users details like surname, first name.

So that I can verify the otp for that user.

Other thing is how can a user will be registered only after OTP verification.

Comment: May be useful https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

Answer (score 0):

The `user_register` hook is fired right after a successful registration.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_theme_registration_do_stuff', 10, 1 );

function my_theme_registration_do_stuff( $user_id ) {

    // the only native way in WP to 'deactivate' a user is to set the role to 'none'. Read up on the implications of this and decide if this will suffice. If not, then you'll need to create some sort of user_meta to use for active/inactive user

    $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
    // Remove role
    $u->remove_role( 'subscriber' ); //or whatever your site's default role is

}
```

Now the user will continue to the next page.

Once the user gets the SMS message with the code and he/she enters the code into some form on your website:

```
  if(the code entered is correct){
      $user = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
      $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
  }
```